# Display data in a two different tables using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Table Name:- subject.
Primary key:- sid

```
*------------------*    
| sid    | sname   |    
*------------------*    
| 1      | C++     |    
| 2      | PHP     |    
| 3      | Java    |    
*------------------*
```

Table Name:- question

Primary key:- qid
  Foreign key:- sid

```
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*    
| qid | sid | question     | ans_one    | ans_two    |  correct_ans        |    
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*    
| 1   |  2  | question 1   | answer one | answer two |  correct answer one |    
| 2   |  3  | question 2   | answer one | answer two |  correct answer two |    
| 3   |  2  | question 3   | answer one | answer two |  correct answer two |    
| 4   |  1  | question 4   | answer one | answer two |  correct answer one |    
| 5   |  2  | question 5   | answer one | answer two |  correct answer one |    
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

these are two tables in a database. I'm going to display all the data in question table using PDO. I codeed to get all the data from the quesion table.

```
    $result = db::$connection->prepare('SELECT `qid`,`sid`,`question`,`ans_one`,`ans_two`,`ans_three`,`ans_four`,`correct_ans`
                        FROM `question`
                        ORDER BY `qid` ASC');
       $result->execute();
       $result->fetchAll();
```

The problem is, I need to display the subject name in the view table. Now it is display the subject id.
How can I do this?

Output must be like this:-

```
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*    
| #   | Subject | Question     | Answer_One    | Answer_One    |  Correct_Ans  |    
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*    
| 1   |  PHP    | question 1   | answer one    | answer two    |  correct answer one |    
| 2   |  Java   | question 2   | answer one    | answer two    |  correct answer two |    
| 3   |  C++    | question 3   | answer one    | answer two    |  correct answer two |            
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

Comment: Note you could just do `$result->execute()->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `JOIN` to get the subject name instead of the id (`sid`):

```
SELECT qid, subject.sname AS sname, question, ans_one, ans_two, correct_ans 
FROM question LEFT JOIN subject ON question.sid = subject.sid
ORDER BY qid ASC
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/key8M32fKAEugHKo6KMAus/0

So you can use the following PHP code:

```
$result = db::$connection->prepare('SELECT qid, subject.sname AS sname, question, ans_one, ans_two, correct_ans 
    FROM question LEFT JOIN subject ON question.sid = subject.sid
    ORDER BY `qid` ASC');
$result->execute();
$result->fetchAll();
```